# Fetched Json data from API is undefined

Tags: reactjs, django, api, react-hooks

I m trying to populate a detail product page with data fetched from my API using useEfect() and useState() hooks in ReactJS, but everytime when i want to print into the console the object fetched it gives me a message with undefined, please help me .

API model:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0, primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, default='no name')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, default='misc_product')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, default='anonim')
    collection = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, default='anonim')
    family = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, default='anonim')
    image_path = models.CharField(max_length=160, null=False, default='')
    likes_no = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    price = models.FloatField(null=False, default=0.00)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.product_name`
```

API Serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product


class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id',
            'product_name',
            'category',
            'author',
            'collection',
            'family',
            'image_path',
            'likes_no',
            'price',
       )
```

API Views

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import ProductSerializer
from .models import Product
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class ProductViewSet(APIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    @classmethod
    def get_extra_actions(cls):
        return []

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data},      status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self, request, id=None):

        if id:
            item = Product.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = ProductSerializer(item)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        items = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(items, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

REACT.JS SCRIPT

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { MessageElement } from './Elements'
import { useParams} from "react-router-dom"
import axios from 'axios'






function DetailProductPage() {
    
        const productId = useParams().productId
    

        const [product, setProduct] = useState([])
        const URL = `http://url/api/products/${productId}`
       
        useEffect(() => {
           axios.get(URL)
            .   then((response) => {
                    setProduct(response.data[0])
                    console.log(product)            
            });
    }, [])
    
        return (
        
            <MessageElement>Detail Page</MessageElement>
            )
```

}

```
export default DetailProductPage
```

RESULT[This is the result i get when i run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hphg.jpg)

PS: I use two terminals, first for API and the second for React Application

Comment: first make sure there is data and also you reach the backend just put a print in the get method and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setProduct(response.data[0]) is an asynchronous method and hence the console would give undefined when trying to see the value in product through console log. If you really want to see the response from api or if the product is getting set in state. You can try the below code.

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { MessageElement } from './Elements'
import { useParams} from "react-router-dom"
import axios from 'axios'

function DetailProductPage() {
    
        const productId = useParams().productId
    

        const [product, setProduct] = useState([])
        const URL = `http://url/api/products/${productId}`
       
        useEffect(() => {
           axios.get(URL)
            .   then((response) => {
                    console.log('response from api', response);
                    setProduct(response.data[0])
                               
            });
    }, [])
        console.log("product set in state", product) 
        return (
        
            <MessageElement>Detail Page</MessageElement>
            )
}
```

Comment: still undefined

Comment: I have edited the code, can you please tell me whats the out put for console log "response from api"

Comment: response from api 
Object { data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
​
config: Object { timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }
​
data: Object { id: 2, product_name: "Squicks the Sherif", category: "Poster", … }
​
headers: Object { "content-length": "242", "content-type": "application/json" }
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }

Comment: You need to expand the response from api  object in chrome console and check whats inside data and form the what you want to set. From the looks of it. response.data is an object {} and not an array. Thats why response.data[0] is resulting in undefined

Comment: @CezarConstantin - Were you able to solve your problem? Do thumbs up if my answered helped you in any way solving the issue